# laravel loop value of table then save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

how to loop the value  of ** table** then save it to database,
i'm having difficulty on how to loop it, meaning save all value here is the link sample https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion.

controller;

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request, [

       'student_name'=>'required|max:50',


            ]);



                    $leads=new Lead();
                    $leads->student_name = $request->student_name;
                    $leads->gender = $request->gender;
                    $leads->age = $request->age;
                    $leads->school = $request->age;
                    $leads->save();
                }
            }

            //Display a successful message upon save
            return redirect()->route('leads.index')
        ->with('flash_message', 'Success.');
}
```

VIEW.CREATE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input name='student_name" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='STUDENT NAME ' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='gender" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='GENDER'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='age" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='AGE'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='school" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='SCHOOL'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });

})
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <div class="row">
    <form action="{{route('leads.store')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
 
    <div class="col-sm-12">
 
    
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
     <tr >
      <th class="text-center">
       #
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       STUDENT NAME
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       GENDER
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       AGE
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       SCHOOL
      </th>
      
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
     <tr id='addr0'>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='student_name' placeholder='STUDENT NAME' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='gender' placeholder='GENDER' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='age'  placeholder='AGE' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='school' placeholder='SCHOOL' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
 
       
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
<a href="{{route('leads.index')}}" class="btn btn-success">CANCEL</a>
</div>
 </form>


<!--end of container-->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what is "input table"?

Comment: check this link bro then tell me how to save multiple value https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion

Comment: You can append [] to input's name, and on php page all youo need to pass them in foreach loop. let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at sending arrays.

By appending `[]` to a input's name, you create a list of values. (Instead of using numbers to give them a unique name.

```
<input name="names[]" value="Hello" />
<input name="names[]" value="World" />
<input name="names[]" value="Test" />
```

Sending the above form will give you the following result:

```
$names = $request->get('names'); // ["Hello", "World", "Test"]
```

Validating arrays also works a bit different. Take a look at the Laravel documentation for that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays